# Can I post questions to fill in the gaps in a textbook I'm reading from?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, self-answer

I am currently reading Galois Theory on my own from Patrick Morandi's *Field and Galois Theory*. There are many statements in the textbook that I do not find to be obvious, which is to be expected from a graduate-level textbook, I think. I would like to post questions to fill in these gaps that I encounter while reading, along with a full solution. I will be posting as and when I encounter an unclear statement and am able to write down a clear explanation, which shouldn't be too often.

I have done this earlier with a couple of question+answer posts while reading Hoffman & Kunze's *Linear Algebra*, and there hasn't been any negative feedback. In fact, one user commented positively that my posts were quite useful for the community. However, I still thought it would be wise to post this on meta before embarking on a potentially long-term series of posts.

So, will such question+answer posts lie within the scope of MSE, and will I be encouraged? Even after going through past discussions on the subject (for example, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15017/279515)), I have not understood the consensus.

Comment: It is hard to say how others will react, but as long as you provide the context of where the problems originate and what you've tried, it *should* be received well.

Comment: @robjohn The format I've been using for the Hoffman&Kunze questions are like this: [example1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2587245/279515) and [example2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2587664/279515). I haven't really shown what I've tried, but I've provided context. Does this look acceptable?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that question.

Comment: Based on your examples: not a PSQ ("problem statement question"), clearly not homework, and you're giving context to your questions. I also don't see any problem.

Comment: I do not see any problem in *posting* either, but my own experience (e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2808055/259671)) is that very concrete questions receive few *answers*.

Comment: Posts like this can be very useful, particularly if you keep track of errors. Just make sure that your questions make sense to those who don't have the book.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I have now made my first such post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2822916/279515).

Comment: @Brahadeesh I've been doing the same with many textbooks, such as _Principles of Mathematics_ by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition; _Topology_ by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition; _A First Course in Abstract Algebra_ by John B. Fraleigh, 7th edition; and a few others. Please have a look at my questions at the following link. https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59734/saaqib-mahmood?tab=questions Saaqib, Abbottabad, Pakistan

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood woah, you have a bazillion questions and answers! Have you also asked and answered your own questions? :)

Comment: @Brahadeesh while I've not explicitly answered my own questions, I certainly have posted complete proofs / solutions as part of my attempt at a question I've posted.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood i see, thank you

Comment: As an off-topic note, for me it seems it could be a very useful feature to add a possibility to tag such questions somewhere along the lines of "following a textbook" with a certain citation/link (since MSE already has a nice bibliography-index available to most popular textbooks). This would allow for easier searching/filtering for future readers, following the same book and likely having similar questions.

Comment: @Nutle: One easy solution is to link to the previous question from each question. That link automatically makes each question appear in the "Linked" section on the right of the previous question, so one can easily browse the whole 'thread' in order.

Comment: Of course, one should already have included a precise bibliographic reference in each post, and if everyone doing this followed that then one can indeed find all posts on that particular text.

Comment: @Nutle I think the idea of having tags for different textbooks has already been discussed in the past (and was rejected)

Comment: I think the main thing is to show in those posts a desire to genuinely understand the textbook. Ideally, that would be enough to distinguish you from the "do-my-homework-for-me" posts.

Comment: Just please make sure you ask a question in each and every post, and don't turn your ongoing posts into a *blog*.  I.e., don't over do it.  But the Question Answer format is a must.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm new here, but I don't see why it would be a problem. From the about page:

> Mathematics Stack Exchange is for people studying mathematics at any
>   level and professionals in related fields. We welcome questions about:
>
> - Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems.
> - **Mathematical problems such as one might come across in a course or textbook. (First read our how to ask a good question
>     page.)**
> - Solving mathematical puzzles.
> - Software that mathematicians use (except    Mathematica, which has its own Stack Exchange site).

Your questions are well educated and provide good discussion and information, I say keep posting them :)

Comment: I browse the new Q's every day and there is almost always a Q on not following part of  book. If the proposer is specific about what part  (s)he does not follow, and quotes the relevant passage, and provides some  necessary definitions (bearing in mind that not all authors use the same notations) there is almost always positive feedback  and an answer.